# Intuitively, why is 3.5 the average (mean) roll of a six-sided die?

Tags: mathematics, random

Every page I could find on the web that answers this question explains it with Expected Value statistic probability math.

$$(1 * \frac 16) + (2 * \frac 16) + (3 * \frac16) + (4 * \frac16) + (5 * \frac16) + (6 * \frac16)$$

O...K... so we have a mathematical formula that tells us the average/mean/expected value but can't we explain it more simply? We have one die with six sides and every time you roll it, one of those six sides has the possibility of being rolled. Without math, why is the Expected Value 3.5?

Comment: Shouldn't that be on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Arguably but the question centers around the 3.5 single die roll statistic that is used heavily in game dev. That math is of secondary concern and the point of the question is to give a simpler explanation, something more physical to grasp onto rather than an equation.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, I wrote a simple program to verify with empirical data that on average we do get a roll of 3.5. (As you tweak the TOTAL_ROLLS closer to 0, the average becomes increasingly unreliable. Although, even at 100 it was still always close to 3.5. But at 10, the average was all over the place.)

```
/*
 * Testing mean of 3.5 for single die roll.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TOTAL_ROLLS 100000

int
main()
{
    int roll_total = 0;

    srand(time(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_ROLLS; ++i)
    {
        int r = rand() % 6;
        roll_total += r + 1;
    }

    double mean = roll_total / (double) TOTAL_ROLLS;

    printf("mean: %f\n", mean);

    return(0);
}
```

Running it few times does in fact verify:

```
mean: 3.496850
mean: 3.502040
mean: 3.497710
mean: 3.497710
mean: 3.503410
mean: 3.494730
mean: 3.494730
```

Now we have a mathematical formula (given in the question) and a program that both tell us the average is 3.5. But WHY?!

### The Answer

The most simple explanation I could come up with is represented in the following image. We have 3 die on the left: 1, 2, 3. And we have 3 die on the right: 4, 5, 6. So what number is exactly in the middle? **3.5**!

[image]

Comment: To expand on why "in the middle" matters: you have as many ways to roll below 3.5 as you have to roll above it, and by equal amounts in each case. So these two will tend to cancel out over long runs. For every 1 I roll (2.5 below average), I'll generally also have rolled a 6 (2.5 above average). For every 2, a 5, for every 3, a 4. So the pull above and below the middle point exactly balance each other.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most intuitive answer is to simply sum up the dots on each side and divide by the number of sides:

```
sum(1,2,3,4,5,6)/6 = 3.5
```

That's the basic meaning of an average (measure of central tendency). And in the case you are describing, it is true that 3.5 falls between 3 and 4, i.e. 3.5. However, if you have some other variations of dots on each side of the die (think of an unfair die), the average may not be in the middle, e.g.:

```
sum(1,1,2,3,5,6)/6 = 3
```

The true middle however, can always be found with the `median`.

I thought adding a plot that shows how these two long run averages converge to the calculated mean values would be helpful too.

[image]